# When to use belongsTo and when hasMany?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If I am not right, please correct me.

There is table `products` and `categories`.

Each product has own category. So, it can be more that one.

So, no I need to select all products by specified category.

What kind of relation I should use in model: `belongsTo`, or `hasMany`?
Is it important sequence?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion...but, can a product have multiple categories (or just one)?

Comment: Product has multiple categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `products` have multiple `categories` and `categories` can have multiple `products`, this is known as a [many-to-many SQL relationship](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561).

If we go to the [Laravel Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you'll see that you want to use `belongsToMany()`. This means, if you want to be able to retrieve all of your `products` from a `category`, you would do something like this (shamelessly copied from Laravel's documentation):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * The products that belong to the category.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

And, of course the other side of this many-to-many relationship is very similar:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The categories that belong to the product.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

---

Now...if you want to fetch all products and subsequently find all categories for each product, you would do something like this:

```
$products = Product::all();
foreach($products as $product) {
    // var_dump($product);

    $categories = $product->categories();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        // var_dump($category);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I get all products by category, may be method `products()` should be in `Product model`?

Comment: In the `Product` model, I would have a similar `categories()` method. This is because, if you have a `$category` object, you would want to be able to get the products from it. In this case, you would be able to say `$category->products()` and it would fetch all products from that many-to-many relationship. If you do the inverse of this on the `Product` model, then you could `$product->categories()` to get a product's categories.

Comment: Okay, then how to call this? Like as: `Product::all()->products();`

Comment: `::all()` returns a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections) which are meant to be looped through. Sorry, but I guess I'm not understanding what your end goal is. `Product::all()` returns a `Collection` or `Product` objects...what do you want to do with that, find the `Categories`? I've updated my question under that assumption.

Comment: I need to  get all products by category. For example select all products where category is 1

Comment: @Putin as long as your models' relationship is defined correctly, you can do that a couple ways. `Products::where('category_id', 1)->get()` or `$category = Category::find(1); $category->products();` would both work.